# Google maps external link forward and back

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hyperlink

I would like to make 2 external links: forward and back to my Google map.
I have searched after it but it would be nice with an example:
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1
                                                            /jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="loadgpx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                  
        function infoOpen(retning)
        {              
         r = r + retning;              
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[r], 'click');
        }
        var gmarkers = [];
        var markers = [];
         var r, retning;  
        markers = [
            ['0', 'Marker 1', 13.988719, 100.617909],
            ['1', 'Marker 2', 13.662811, 100.43758],
            ['2', 'Marker 3', 13.744961, 100.535073],
            ['3','Marker 4', 13.801981, 100.613864],
            ['4', 'Marker 5', 13.767507, 100.644024]];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myOptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };             
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
            new google.maps.Size(65, 32),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(18, 42));
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();             
            var marker, i;                
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
                var content = markers[i][1];
                bounds.extend(pos);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map
                });
                gmarkers.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, content));
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    </script>
    <style>   
                body {
            text-align: center
        }
        #map {
            width:640px;

             height: 480px;
            border:6px solid #6f5f5e;
            margin:20px auto 30px auto;
        }
</style>   
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen(1);">back</a> 
 <a href="javascript:void  (0);" onclick="infoOpen('+1');">forward</a>
 <div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can only find examples with a link per marker, but i need a Forward and Back link.

Comment: What do you mean with a forward and back button. What should they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.
You need to set a default value for `r` and remove the quotes in your link: `infoOpen('+1');`. It should just be `infoOpen(1);` and `infoOpen(-1);` for backwards:

```
function infoOpen(retning) {
    r = r + retning;
    // Don't get out of bounds
    if (r >= gmarkers.length) r = 0;
    if (r < 0) r = gmarkers.length - 1;
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[r], 'click');
}

var gmarkers = [];
var r = 0, retning;
var markers = [
    ['0', 'Marker 1', 13.988719, 100.617909],
    ['1', 'Marker 2', 13.662811, 100.43758],
    ['2', 'Marker 3', 13.744961, 100.535073],
    ['3', 'Marker 4', 13.801981, 100.613864],
    ['4', 'Marker 5', 13.767507, 100.644024]
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
    new google.maps.Size(65, 32),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(18, 42));
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
        var content = markers[i][1];
        bounds.extend(pos);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, content));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

I also added 2 lines in your `infoOpen` function that will keep the index in `gmarkers` in bounds.
And your buttons:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen(-1);">back</a>  
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen(1);">forward</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd5Tf/2/)